# Updating a table & inserting data from another table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS music 
(
songname    varchar(98) DEFAULT NULL,
songartist  varchar(29) DEFAULT NULL,
songalbum   varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
albumID     INT,
songlength  decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
songgenre   varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
songyear    int DEFAULT NULL,
songplays   INT DEFAULT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albumList
(
    ID_num INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    albumName VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_num)
);
```

This is for a project in my IT201 class. The question, word for word, is:

> Update the music table to set the albumID number to the corresponding album ID number from the new album table.  (Hint: use a nested select statement.)

I've done stuff like this before with no problem, I really enjoy this language, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried every iteration of UPDATE I can think of, I even tried some INSERT commands, JOINing the tables..I just don't know. Here is a sample of one of my latest attempts:

```
UPDATE music
SET
music.albumID = (SELECT albumList.albumName FROM albumList)
```

Obviously I have not included the INSERT statements from either table that make up the data, I felt it was irrelevant for this question. Just understand that there are about 1000 rows worth of entries in table.music and about 200 in table.albumList.

The idea is that albumList is a table for unique album names, whereas music has many that repeats. I am trying to update music.albumID to correspond to the albumList.ID_num. I am under the impression this is not done with JOINs or foreign keys/referencing, because the next question is to add a foreign key that references these. So I assume this can be done with UPDATE and nested SELECTS before that, as the question hints at.

Comment: your update won't work. that subselect will return MULTIPLE rows of data, and you can't assign (`=`) a result SET to a single field. you need to look into update's `join` syntax...

Comment: you need to do a join in your update statement.  Something like update music set music.albumID = AL.ID_num from music inner join albumList AL on AL.albumName = music.songalbum  (since this is homework, I'm not giving you the exact query, just an idea)

Comment: I appreciate this, this is definitely homework, I like that the instructor (and you) don't give exact answers. I tried a JOIN earlier but it didn't work, but thank you for putting me on the right path. :)

Also thanks for editting the formatting @Barranka

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL should help, though I am assuming that songalbum on `music` contains the same data as `albumname` on albumList (this may be incorrect since the field sizes are different).  It sets the `albumID` on `music` to be the `ID_Num` from `albumList` where the `songalbum` matches the `albumName`

```
UPDATE music  SET albumID = (SELECT a.ID_Num FROM albumList a  
                                Join music m on m.songalbum = a.albumName)
```

Comment: I tried something very similar to this, but I always get an error whenever I use a JOIN command inside of a select statement underneath the UPDATE command.

Error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'music' for update in FROM clause

`UPDATE music
SET 
albumID = (SELECT albumList.ID_Num FROM albumList JOIN music ON music.songalbum = albumList.albumName)`

This did make me realize that I had a brain fart, and was doing the previous attempts wrong. I wasn't making sure the songalbum matched the albumName, like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with your guys' help, I solved the answer. I did not require a JOIN statement, as I always thought in the first place. The assignment is due by noon today (in 10 minutes) and the battery on my laptop is very close to dead, so I didn't have much time to confirm my answer was what I wanted, but a cursory check confirms that I got the right answer (and what the question hints the answer is). I thought I'd post it for anyone else that wants to search SOF in the future:

`UPDATE music
SET 
albumID = (SELECT albumList.ID_Num FROM albumList WHERE albumList.albumName = music.songalbum)`